# Regex to filter only the first occurance of specific strings

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following output from a command substituted variable:

```
'Enable succeeded: [stdout]Proc is not up yet, retrying...Proc is not up yet, retrying...Proc is not up yet, retrying...Proc is not up yet, retrying...Proc is not up yet, retrying...Proc is not up yet, retrying...[stderr]'
```

The string **Proc is not up yet, retrying...** might appear an unknown amount of times and as I need to capture one occurance only, I'm using **grep -o -m1** for that purpose, which does work. The problem is that I need to allow my variable to capture multiple different specific strings as well (e.g. **Proc is up and running!**), which similarly can appear an unknown amount of times.

Note that every occurrence of the string is separated by a newline, and ideally I would like to also strip the last \n which remains at the very end of the string when I use grep -m1.

Comment: `every occurrence of the string is separated by a newline` - then why in "the following output" are there no newlines? `allow my variable to capture multiple` - you mean `grep "Proc is not up yet, retrying..\|Proc is up and running!"` ?

Comment: Ah yes, because what I'm showing you is parsed with 'tr -d '\n' which strips newlines. However I found out that I cannot use this statement together with grep -m1, therefore the need to strip the last newline. Also yes, the answer you wrote will work, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grep multiple expressions, delimit them with `\|` like so:

```
grep "Proc is not up yet, retrying...\|Proc is up and running!"
```

Answer (score 0):

perl to the rescue!

```
$ cat lines.txt
This matches regexp a.
This also matches regexp a.
This matches regexp b.
This also matches regexp a.
And this matches regexp b.
$ perl -nE 'say $& if m?regexp a? || m?regexp b?' lines.txt
regexp a
regexp b
```

Comment: I thought about this, but unfortunately installing perl is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked for a regex, but perhaps using **uniq** is sufficient:

#### Before

```
Proc is not up yet, retrying...
>!#<@!<@
Proc is not up yet, retrying...
Proc is up and running!

Proc is up and running!
Proc is up and running!
??????????????????????????????
Proc is up and running!

Proc is done running.
```

#### After

```
cat sample_text | grep -o '^Proc is.*' | uniq
```

---

```
Proc is not up yet, retrying...
Proc is up and running!
Proc is done running.
```

If you find it useful, be sure to take a look at it's *man page*, for features like counting the repeated lines and such - might come in handy!

Comment: Also a very good solution, but then I need to adjust all strings to start the same way. It might sound kind of lame, but I prefer to use the whole thing.

Comment: Glad you like it, even though you've found a better one. And hey, there's nothing lame in being picky when it comes to programming/scripting - searching for the perfect solution makes you learn more stuff :)